# glMapBuffer() and glBuffers, how does the access with a (void*) work with hardware?

Tags: opengl, hardware

Reading through the OpenGL Programming Guide, 8th Edition.

This is really a hardware question, actually...

I come to a section on OpenGL buffers, and as far as I understand they are memory spaces allocated in graphics card memory, is this correct?

If so, how are we able to get a pointer to read or modify that memory using glMapBuffer() ? As far as I was aware, all possible memory addresses (eg on a 64bit system there are `uint64_t num = 0x0; num = ~num;` possible addresses) were used for system memory as in RAM / CPU side Memory.

glMapBuffers() returns a void* to some memory. How can that pointer point to memory inside the graphics card? Particularly if I had a 32 bit system, and more than 4GB of RAM, and then a Graphics Card with say 2GB/4GB of memory. Surely there aren't enough addresses?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is really a hardware question, actually...

No it's not. You'll see why in a moment.

> I come to a section on OpenGL buffers, and as far as I understand they are memory spaces allocated in graphics card memory, is this correct?

Not quite. You must understand that while OpenGL gets you really close to the actual hardware, you're still very far from touching it directly. What glMapBuffer does is, that it sets up a virtual address range mapping. On modern computer systems the software doesn't operate on physical addresses. Instead a virtual address space (of some size) is used. This virtual address space looks like one large contiguous block of memory to the software, while in fact its backed by a patchwork of physical pages. Those pages can be implemented anyhow, they can be actual physical memory, they can be I/O memory, they can even be created in-situ by another program. The mechanism for that is provided by the CPU's Memory Management Unit in collaboration with the OS.

So for each process the OS manages a table of which part of the process virtual address space maps to what page handler. If you're running Linux have a look at `/proc/$PID/maps`. If you have a program that uses *glMapBuffer* read (with your program, don't call system) `/proc/self/maps` before and after the map buffer and look for the differences.

> As far as I was aware, all possible memory addresses (eg on a 64bit system there are uint64_t num = 0x0; num = ~num; possible addresses) were used for system memory as in RAM / CPU side Memory.

What makes you think that? Whoever told you that (if somebody told you that) should be slapped in the face… hard.

What you have is a virtual address space. And this address space is completely different from the physical address space on the hardware side. In fact the size of the virtual address space and the size of physical address spaces can differ largely. For example for a long time there were 32 bit CPUs and 32 bit operating systems around. But already then it was desireable to have more than 4 GiB of system memory. So while the CPU would support only 32 bits of address space for a process (maximum size of a pointer), it may have provided 36 bits of physical address lines to memory, to support some 64 GiB of system RAM; it would then be the OS's job to manually switch those extra bits, so that while each process sees only some 3 GiB of system RAM (max.) processes in total could spread. A technique like that has become known as Physical Address Extension (PAE).

Furthermore not all of the address space in a process are backed by RAM. Like I already explained, address space mappings could be backed by anything. Often the memory pagefault handler will also implement swapping, i.e. if there's not enough free RAM around it will use HDD storage (in fact on Linux all userspace requests for memory are backed by the *Disk I/O Cache* handler). Also since the address space mappings are per process, some part of the address space is mapped kernel memory, which is the (physically) same for all processes and also resides at the same place in all processes. From user space this address space mapping is not accessible, but as soon as a syscall makes a transistion into kernel space it gets accessible; yes the OS kernel uses virtual memory internally, too. It just can't choose as broadly from the available backings (for example it would be very difficult for a network driver to operate, if its memory was backed by the network itself).

Anyway: On modern 64 bit systems you got a 64 bit pointer size, and with current hardware there are 48 bits of physical RAM address lines. Which leaves plenty of space, namely 16 × 48 bits (*EDIT* which means 2^16 - 1 times a 48 bit address space), for virtual mappings where there's no RAM around. And because there's so much to go around, each and every PCI card gets its very own address space, that behaves a little bit like RAM to the CPU (remember those PAE I mentioned earlier, well, in good old 32 bit times something like that had to be done to talk with extension cards already).

Now here comes the OpenGL driver. It simply provides a new address mapping handler, that usually just builds on top of the PCI address space handler, which will map a portion of virtual address space of a process. And whatever happens in that address space will be reflected by that mapping handler into a buffer ultimately accessed by the GPU. However the GPU itself may be accessing CPU memory directly. And what AMD plans is, that GPU and CPU will live on the same Die and access the same memory, so there's no longer a physical distinction there.

Comment: That last part, as far as I was aware you have just described the AMD APU. Intel Core cpus also have a system-on-chip CPU, GPU and memory controller, as far as I am aware. The raspberry pi also uses a similar design, although I couldn't tell you the specifics of it. The GPUs in all three may still be seen as separate physical systems, I don't know.

Comment: @EdwardBird: That's indeed that case. But what I was actually thinking of, when writing that paragraph, is the next generation of AMD APUs, where CPU and GPU share the MMU, which effectively means, that they will use the very same address space and the GPU becomes an actual coprocessor unit, just like the FPU is. I hope that in 2 or 3 years, should AMD pull this off, their top range APUs will (hopefully) reach performance similar to a GTX680, which would be really interesting for me.

Comment: Might be a bit of a disaster for low-budget consumers if graphics cards become extinct. Why don't they re-design the pci-e interface and replace it with something faster? At the moment it operates at 100MHz I think, which seems rather slow. I don't know how many bits are transferred each clock cycle, but it should be fairly simple to get a data bus working 64 bits wide in and out. I'm guessing the SOC approach gives better IO performance than I described?

Comment: At the moment by the way both APU's and HD graphics 4000 - well, they are kind of crap performance wise. One problem I have is my i7 with HD 4000 supports up to OpenGL 3.0 only. (Basically you're stuck in Version 2.0 / 2.1 territory.)

Comment: @datenwolf: Aren't memory controllers in discrete GPUs typically much higher bandwidth than the CPU iMMU?  From that, I would expect that APUs will provide a large boost to CPU memory bandwidth before the graphics performance comes anywhere close to a GTX680.

Comment: @EdwardBird: 100MHz on PCIe?!?! You wish. PCIe is one serious case of RF where you need oscilloscopes with at least 40GHz signal bandwidths to analyze the properties of the signal. Also it's low-budget consumers that benefit most from integrated high performance GPU/CPU combos. It's the high performance computing folks (to which I blong) that really suffer. Oh well, I don't pay the bills.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's indeed the case. We're talking about a factor of 10 here, right now. But give it two years (aka 3 generations of CPU and 4 generations of GPU design and the corresponding advances in I/O technology).

Comment: @datenwolf: I think he's referring to the PCIe clock signal, which ISTR is nominally 100MHz.  But DDR methods are used for the data, yielding a much higher throughput.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is exactly what I was referring to, as far as I was aware that is the speed at which the PICe bus operates.

Comment: @EdwardBird: This is the clock base frequency. But the PCIe bus actually operates at much higher frequencies. Same concept at CPU cores getting fed by a 32MHz oscillator and multiplying it up to several GHz using a PLL.

Answer (score 2):

`glMapBuffers()` returns a pointer in the virtual memory space of the application, that's why the pointer could point in something above 4GB on a 64bits system.

The memory you manipulate with the mapped pointer could be a cpu copy (shadow) of the texture(or buffer) allocated on gpu or it could be the actual texture moved to system memory. It's often the operating system who decides if a texture resides on system memory or gpu memory. The operating system can move the texture from one location to another and can make a copy of it (shadow)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the OpenGL implementation that decides if the texture should be in GPU memory or RAM? And shouldn't be the OpenGL implementation that moves the texture from one location to another?

Comment: @Shahbaz Opengl mostly specifies the user interface and leaves its implementation to the driver. The driver decides where a texture should reside. In some os like windows vista (and newer versions) the os virtualizes the memory (even the vram) and the driver gives final control of the resource location to the os.

Comment: That still sounds strange to me. The OS shouldn't get involved in what is most efficient for graphical processing (whether texture should be in RAM or graphics card memory), but the driver would. So even if OpenGL leaves that to the driver (which makes sense), the driver should be able to force the OS to do what it says, no?

Comment: @Shahbaz Yes the driver should know what is best for graphics performance and it's the one making the requests. The memory is virtualized and windows (WDDM) manages this virtual memory and reports back to the driver. The driver has to be compliant to WDDM model and this has the drawback of limiting its control (limiting control is not always a bad thing).

Answer (score 2):

Computers have multiple layers of memory mapping.  First all physically addressable components (including RAM, PCI memory windows, other device registers, etc) are all assigned a physical address.  The size of this address varies.  Even on 32-bit Intel devices the physical space might be a 36-bit address (to the CPU) while it is a 64-bit address in the PCI memory space.

On top of that mapping is a virtual mapping.  There are many different virtual mappings, including one for each process.  Within that space (which on a 64-bit system is as huge as you say) any combination (including repeats!) of physical space can be mapped as long as it fits.  On a 64-bit system the available virtual space is so large that every possible physical device could easily be mapped.

Comment: ... so ... glMapBuffer() returns a pointer to some data in system memory or graphics side memory? Good answer so far though, that helped me understand system memory a lot better.

Comment: @EdwardBird: When parsing specifications like this you have to consider that the people writing the spec did not want to dictate to the implementers exactly how something must work.  Your supposition is reasonable, but note, "A mapped data store must be unmapped with glUnmapBuffer before its buffer object is used".  That's a hint that the API gets a crack at doing something (say, DMA'ing the data back to the GPU!) after you're done.  As a user you get a specified effect but you don't know the implementation.